# Picklist Sum Formula Question

Tags: formula, picklist

I received a request to create 20 numerical picklist fields and a formula summing the chosen numerical character. In this case, it is merely adding several selected numerical picklist value to each other. Because they are picklist values, I used the TEXT function to convert the picklist value to text.

Then I encapsulated that by a VALUE function to revert it to a number, without the picklist formula restrictions. However, this formula is only working when it has two fields added together, only. So, if I remove 18 of the lines and only add two fields, it works perfectly.

Once I add a third, fourth, fifth, etc… field to add, no value is output. The output is a complete blank, regardless of what picklist values are selected. Can anyone lend me some advice? Below is the formula in question. Thank you.

```
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Form__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Contract_Language__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_License_Grant__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Content_Options__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Exclusivity__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Term__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Termination__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Pricing_for_Multiyear__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Payment_Terms__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Invoicing__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Service_Level_Agreement__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Rep_Warranty__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Limitation_of_Liability__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Indemnity_Hold_Harmless__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Assignment__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Code_App_Ownership__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Data_Ownership_if_SVU__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Change_of_Control__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Choice_of_Law_Venue__c))+ 
VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Insurance_Obligations__c))
```

Comment: Just shooting in the dark, but you might need to add a check that the values are not blank, e.g. `IF(ISPICKVAL(Contract_Rating_Form__c, 0, VALUE(TEXT(Contract_Rating_Form__c))))`.

Comment: That or tell the formula field to treat blank fields as zeros

Comment: Have you tried wrapping each set of sums in parentheses?

Comment: I've have told the formula field to treat blanks as zeros, but still having the error.

Comment: BinaryLady: Can you give me an example when I want the end result to sum all values, regardless of order?